# custom Iterator Index out of bounds

Tags: c#, iterator

i am making a custom iterator for my class assignment and i have getting an index out of bounds, but i don't see where. 
When i debug it it stops on the last iteration (count 39, stops at index 39)

I am not sure where in the iterator the problem persists.

```
public override bool NextCourse(DataSet courseDS, DataView courseView, ref int currIndex)
{
    if (courseView.Count == 0)
        return false; 

    int nextIndex = currIndex + 1;


    if (nextIndex >= courseView.Count -1)
    {
        currIndex = nextIndex;
        return true;
    }

    if (currIndex < 0)
    {
        currIndex = 0;
        return true;
    }

    string currCourseNumber = (string)courseView[currIndex][(int)CourseListQueries.GetCourseListCols.CourseNumber];
    string courseNumber = String.Empty;

    currIndex++;

    do
    {
        courseNumber = (string)courseView[currIndex][(int)CourseListQueries.GetCourseListCols.CourseNumber];
        if ( String.Compare(courseNumber, currCourseNumber,true) != 0 ) 
            break;
        currIndex++;
    }
    while (currIndex < courseView.Count);

    return (currIndex < courseView.Count);
}// end NextCourse
```

stack trace:

```
 Index 39 is either negative or above rows count.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 39 is either negative or above rows count.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 39 is either negative or above rows count.]
   System.Data.DataView.GetRow(Int32 index) +5259337
   System.Data.DataView.get_Item(Int32 recordIndex) +12
   FIMS_Courses.Controls.CourseTable.GradTable.GradTable.InitializeControls(GenericContainer container) +4978
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.SimpleView.CreateChildControls() +52
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace, and indicate where you're getting the exception. (I'd try to use an iterator block if you possibly can... this all looks very complicated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do seem to have a check against the final iteration, but it is outputting true. 
how are you calling the iterator? I am assuming it is in a while loop structure because it's a bool type.

I think if you made this change it should work

```
if (nextIndex >= courseView.Count ) //to last element, yours is at second last.
    {
        currIndex = nextIndex;
        return false;// make it false, it should terminate and end loop . 
    }
```